# Question regarding UIImage -> CVPixelBuffer -> UIImage conversion

Tags: swift, uiimage, coreml, cvpixelbuffer

I am working on a simple denoising POC in SwiftUI where I want to:

1. Load an input image
2. Apply a CoreML model (denoising) to the input image
3. Display the output image

I have something working based on dozens of source codes I found online. Based on what I've read, a CoreML model (at least the one I'm using) accepts a CVPixelBuffer and outputs also a CVPixelBuffer. So my idea was to do the following:

1. Convert the input UIImage into a CVPixelBuffer
2. Apply the CoreML model to the CVPixelBuffer
3. Convert the newly created CVPixelBuffer into a UIImage

(Note that I've read that using the Vision framework, one can input a CGImage directly into the model. I'll try this approach as soon as I'm familiar with what I'm trying to achieve here as I think it is a good exercise.)

As a start, I wanted to skip the step (2) to focus on the conversion problem. What I tried to achieve in the code bellow is:

1. Convert the input UIImage into a CVPixelBuffer
2. Convert the CVPixelBuffer into a UIImage

I'm not a Swift or an Objective-C developer, so I'm pretty sure that I've made at least a few mistakes. I found this code quite complex and I was wondering if there was a better / simpler way to do the same thing?

```swift
func convert(input: UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    // Input CGImage
    guard let cgInput = input.cgImage else {
        return nil
    }

    // Image size
    let width = cgInput.width
    let height = cgInput.height
    let region = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

    // Attributes needed to create the CVPixelBuffer
    let attributes = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue,
                      kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue]

    // Create the input CVPixelBuffer
    var pbInput:CVPixelBuffer? = nil
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                     width,
                                     height,
                                     kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB,
                                     attributes as CFDictionary,
                                     &pbInput)

    // Sanity check
    if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
        return nil
    }

    // Fill the input CVPixelBuffer with the content of the input CGImage
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pbInput!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
    guard let context = CGContext(data: CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pbInput!),
                                  width: width,
                                  height: height,
                                  bitsPerComponent: cgInput.bitsPerComponent,
                                  bytesPerRow: cgInput.bytesPerRow,
                                  space: cgInput.colorSpace!,
                                  bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue) else {
                                    return nil
    }
    context.draw(cgInput, in: region)
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pbInput!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

    // Create the output CGImage
    let ciOutput = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pbInput!)
    let temporaryContext = CIContext(options: nil)
    guard let cgOutput = temporaryContext.createCGImage(ciOutput, from: region) else {
        return nil
    }

    // Create and return the output UIImage
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgOutput)
}
```

When I used this code in my SwiftUI project, input and output images looked the same, but there were not identical. I think the input image had a colormap (ColorSync Profile) associated to it that have been lost during the conversion. I assumed I was supposed to use `cgInput.colorSpace` during the CGContext creation, but it seemed that using `CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!` was working better. Can somebody please explain that to me?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `CGImage` objects with Core ML, but you have to create the `MLFeatureValue` object by hand and then put it into an `MLFeatureProvider` to give it to the model. But that only takes care of the model input, not the output.

Another option is to use the code from my [CoreMLHelpers](https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers) repo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll give it a try as it might simplify my code, especially the `CGImage` to `CVPixelBuffer` conversion. But in any case I have to deal with the CVPixelBuffer to UIImage conversion.

Comment: That is pretty simple: `let image = UIImage(ciImage: CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer))`.

Comment: For some reason `let image = UIImage(ciImage: CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer))` doesn't work. I had to use a `CIContext` and then use `createCGImage` to make it work. But I'm really not confident with the code I have. This is why I created this post.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision. By "not working" I meant that my output image is  totally white. I must have done something wrong I guess.

Comment: You mean you always get a totally white image? In that case, I'd try running the model from Python to see what you get there.

Comment: I'm not even using the model here. If I replace in the code above the last part where I convert the CVPixelBuffer into a UIImage using what you proposed, the output image is white. But it is fine with the original code.